# Binding data to request object in middleware [Slim Framework 3]

Tags: php, slim

I am decoding jwt tokens in the middleware following [this](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/middleware.html#route-middleware) example in the documentation of slim framework. Now i want to bind `userid` decoded from the jwt token into the request object. This is how we do it in expressjs but i can't figure out how to do it in slim framework. Is there anyway to bind data into the request object?

I tried:

```
$request->setParam('userid', $userId);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I have solved this problem. This is how we can bind data to request object in slim framework.

```
$request = $request->withAttribute('userid', $userId);
```

And in the route or controller, this is how we can get data:

```
$userId = $request->getAttribute('userid');
```

Comment: Well done! The important lesson is that the Request object is immutable, so you need to copy the modified `$request` into a new variable. A question back though - in your question's code you used method as a L-value (`$request->setParam('userid') = $userId;`). I am not aware of such feature in PHP except for a special `list()` construct - can you please enlighten me on it?

Comment: You're right. This was a mistake i made.. I just copied the code and pasted it here as i was trying everything to achieve the result. I am coming from nodejs and this is how we do it in express `req.user = userid;`. Anyways, i have updated the code in the question.